# How to index, remove and count all instances of an element within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am new to Python and I am trying to learn something about lists. In this case, my objective is to index, count and remove all instances of an element within a list. The indexing, counting and removing all works fine separately, yet I am struggling to merge it and get the desired results. What am I doing wrong?

```
def removing(letter,lst):
    '''This function should index and remove all entries of a letter within a list, returning the removed items' position within the original list. I then use len() function on the result-list to determine how many items have been indexed/deleted'''
    result=[]
    offset= -1
    list_new = lst.copy()
    while True:
        try:
            offset=list_new.index(letter, offset+1)
        except ValueError:
            return result
            print('Letter not found.')
        result.append(offset)
        lst.remove(letter)
```

Now I expected that even without cloning the list, this would do the trick, and the function returns the letters' positions and removes them, but when I define `lst` and `letter`, run the function and then say:

```
print(len(removing(letter,lst)))
```

It always says 0. Why is that?

EDIT: I have been advised to call the function once and store the result, yet I when I do the following, the result is the same:

```
c=1
print(lst)
while (c==1):
    letter=input('What letter do you want to remove?\n')
    if letter in lst:
        var=removing(letter,lst)
        print(var)
        print(str(len(var))+' letters have been removed.')
        print(lst)
    else:
        c-1
```

Comment: What inputs are you testing this with?  The first few I tried seem to work fine.

Comment: Just a small issue, but having `print('Letter not found.')` after your return statement... that line will never be executed.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Ok, good to know, why though? :-)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh For input I use (testwise):

satz='Dies soll in eine Liste übertragen werden.'
   lst=[]
   lst.extend(satz)

Comment: Is this function supposed to modify the passed in list?  `lst.remove(letter)` is removing all of the letters from `lst`, so when you call `removing` again, there are 0 of that letter left in the list.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes it is supposed to modify the passed list. If I try to modifiy the cloned list, I can not access it with print()... Is there a way to do that in a different way?

Comment: So your problem is that you're calling it twice. The second time, there are no letters to remove.  Call the function once, and store the result.

Comment: Yes.  In general, if you have to add multiple lines of code to a comment, that comment should be either an edit to the question or an answer instead.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Question has been edited. Thank you for the advice so far :-)

Comment: As for your [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404313/how-to-index-remove-and-count-all-instances-of-an-element-within-a-list?noredirect=1#comment95622459_54404313), it's in the nature of the `return` statement to immediately exit the function. As a result, the line following the return statement (`print('Letter not found')`) will never be executed.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Understood.

Comment: All strings in Python are already lists and why not just use ```re.sub()``` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop isn't necessary, and will loop infinitely.  Try the below

```
lst = list('abracadabra')
letter = 'a'

var=removing(letter,lst)
print(var)  # [0, 3, 5, 7, 10]
print(str(len(var))+' letters have been removed.')  # 5 letters have been removed.
print(lst)  # ['b', 'r', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'r']
```

Another way of writing the function in a slightly more pythonic way would be something like

```
def remove(lst, item):
    new_list = []
    indices = []
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x == item:
            indices.append(i)
        else:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list, indices
```

Comment: You are right. I made the loop just to perform this repeatedly. And thank you again.

Comment: Would not be simpler using r```e.sub``` like  ```re.sub('a', '', 'abracadabra')```?

Comment: @accdias That doesn't meet the requirement of returning a list of the removed indices.

Comment: Oh! I see. So ```re.finditer()``` could be used instead.

Comment: Something like this ```[i.span()[0] for i in re.finditer('a', 'abracadabra')]``` would give the indices list of all ocurrences of  ```a```  in ```abracadabra```.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, my question has been answered. The problem was not in the function but it was me calling the function multiple times without storing the result. Final code looks like this:

```
    lst= list('Nach langem rumprobieren haben nette Menschen mir bei der Vollendung dieser kleinen Übungsaufgabe geholfen.')

    def removing(letter,lst):
        'This function should remove all entries of a letter within a list'
    result=[]
    offset= -1
    list_new = lst.copy()
    while True:
        try:
            offset=list_new.index(letter, offset+1)
        except ValueError:
            return result
        result.append(offset)
        lst.remove(letter)

    c=1
    print(lst)
    while (c==1):
        letter=input('What letter do you want to remove?\n')
        if letter in lst:
            var=removing(letter,lst)
            print(var)
            print(str(len(var))+' letters have been removed.')
            print(lst)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Note that your `c-1` doesn;t actually change the value of `c`.  Try `c -= 1` instead.  (Or just `break`)

Comment: *facepalm* Should have noticed that when the break never happened.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import re

def removing(c, s):
    '''This function removes all occurences of 'c' in 's' and return a list of the replaced indices'''
    indices = [i.span()[0] for i in re.finditer(c, s)]
    return s.replace(c, ''), indices
```

And here is the usage example:

```
>>> removing('a', 'abracadabra')
('brcdbr', [0, 3, 5, 7, 10])
>>> 
>>> removing('a', 'aaaaa')
('', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>>
```

Comment: Interesting. I knew none of these operators. Will look into them. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help you and it would be great if you mark one of the answers as valid to solve the problem. That will certainly help other users with the same question.